# How to enter license key for virtualized Windows?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, license

Generally, how is `Windows 10` run on `Linux`?

By which I mean, once the ISO is downloaded how is licensing dealt with?

see also:

https://superuser.com/q/1541418/55747

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally when you run Windows under Linux you run it in a hypervisor like VirtualBox. This is a virtual server, and you have a console just like you have on a physical Machine. Also the installation ptocess is the same, so somewhere on the way you enter the license key, the same way and place you do on a physical installation.

Comment: this is getting circular in that, from what I gather from super user, there's no actual license key.  Or perhaps no unique key.  Or that the key is stored in UEFI and not readily accessible....but I wasn't intending to ask *how* to get the license.

Comment: @Thufir how do you activate a Window inst, if windows was installed without license ? Ask in A Windows group. VirtualBox and other hypervisors (vmware, kvm ..) emulates a physical server, incl. bios and all. Your physical server's bios/uefi will not be available in the virtual environment.

Comment: This answer is correct. I use Windows in a VM every day. Yes indeed, you need your license key (which is simply an alphanumeric string you purchased from Microsoft) to install Windows in a VM. Yes indeed you enter the key string during install. Yes, the VM Hypervisor stores the key, not the real machine UEFI.